# Calculation of surface integral without parameters

Tags: integration, surface-integrals

Yesterday ago we learnt about surface integrals, and I already calculated some with parameters.

One of these exercises was this one:

$x= v\cos(u)$

$y= \sin(u)$

$z= v$

while $B' = {(u,v): 0 \le  u \le  \pi, 0 \le  v \le  h\sin(u))}$

this was very simple, as we were given a relatively solid explanation of how to calculate the surface distortion factor N by calculating $\sqrt{A²+B²+C²}$, while A,B,C are the corresponding Iacobi matrices.
(I hope this is an international known way to calculate this - I am studying in Germany).

However, now I am facing an exercise where all I am given is:

$z = x*y$ as an area somewhere in my coordinate system.

Now, I have to calculate the surface of this area, but only of the part which is located above $x²+y² \le 1$.

I am pretty sure what I am calculating, but I just can't find a way to push this into a format which is applicable for the formulas I know.

Currently, I am trying to do it like this:

$u = x$

$v = y$

However, I think this is somewhat too idiotic, and that there is a special way to do it without parameters.

Can anyone of you help me? My main problem right now is to calculate the surface distortion factor. I think calculating the integral itself later on is pretty straightforward, considering the use of polar coordinates which come to my mind when reading about the given circle $x² + y² \le 1$

Comment: I would just do as you are trying.  Basically, you are looking for the surface area of the graph $z=f(x,y)$.  If you use this with $x=x$ and $y=y$ for the other coordinates (or $x=u$, $y=v$), then you can get a general formula for the distortion factor of graphs.  This factor involves the partial derivatives of $f$.

Comment: I am currently on it, but I am getting some pretty ridiculous values when I try it that way: Is it correct that I have to use x² + y² <= 1 to get to x = sqrt(1-y²) and y = sqrt(1-x²)? Those two functions are driving me crazy right now

Comment: I also found a way to do it with the partial derivatives to x and y and then using the cross product as my new integrand. What do you think about that?

Comment: Yes, the second comment that you made is what I was referring to.

Comment: If you are intending to use polar coordinates, then you can also use $x= v \cos u$, $y = v\sin u$, and convert $z$ using these.  Then the cross product, using derivatives with respect to $u$ and $v$, can be used.